# Download csv file from another ftp server and modify

Tags: php, ftp

My ftp credentials are correct. I've my php code uploaded on one server let's say [example.com](http://example.com) and on this server I'm trying to download csv file present on [example2.com](http://example2.com) . Though it shows problem while downloading.

```
<?php
$ftp_server = "ftp.example.com";

$remote_file = 'amit.csv';
$local_file = 'amit2.csv';

// open some file to write to
$handle = fopen($local_file, 'w');

// set up basic connection
$conn_id = ftp_connect($ftp_server);

// login with username and password
$login_result = ftp_login($conn_id, 'user@example2.com', 'mypassword');

// try to download $remote_file and save it to $handle
if (ftp_fget($conn_id, $handle, $remote_file, FTP_ASCII, 0)) {
 echo "successfully written to $local_file\n";
} else {
 echo "There was a problem while downloading $remote_file to $local_file\n";
}

// close the connection and the file handler
ftp_close($conn_id);
fclose($handle);
?>
```

I want to download/read amit.csv, make some modification and upload on one another server [example3.com](http://example3.com). How I should go about it?

Comment: "it shows problem while downloading" what problems, can you be more specific ?

Comment: @Loufylouf: Error is `There was a problem while downloading amit.csv to amit2.csv `

Comment: Ok, is `$login_result` equal to `true` ?

Comment: Yes, I tried `if($login_result) {echo "true";} ` and it works.

Comment: Great, we're progressing. Have you tried another command, like for example `ftp_nlist` (which will also make sure you are in the right directory ?

Comment: I've tried `$file = fopen ("ftp.example2.com/amit.csv", "w");
if (!$file) {
    echo "<p>Unable to open remote file for writing.\n";
    exit;
}` and it says `Unable to open remote file for writing`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/106942/discussion-between-loufylouf-and-amitshree).